# Copy view mode custom settings

Tags: nodes, entities

On /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display I can enable custom display settings for various view modes. But what if I want one custom view mode to be almost identical to another? Is there a way to copy the settings of a certain view mode to another view mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any built in way of doing this. I'm sure you could make a custom module that could do this, but it wont exactly be trivial.

What makes this a bit tricky, is that the information is store many different places. Each field has it's weight stored in the `field_config_instance` table, which holds general information about the field, like widget settings etc. The weights for all the extra fields for the entity/bundle is saved as a key to the `field_bundle_settings` variable that can be accessed with `variable_get`.

If you want to explore this you can take a look at the [`field_ui_display_overview_form_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field_ui--field_ui.admin.inc/function/field_ui_display_overview_form_submit/7) function which is responsible for saving the display info.

Comment: Thanks. A custom module sounds like an interesting idea, but for now, I'll just do things manually.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) in combination with [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features), it will allow you to export your custom settings